# Javascript - about Objects

Tags: javascript, function, object

I would like to know if this is possible:
I want to access a index of an object that point for another index in the same object..
example:

```
var object = {
    edit: function (string) {
        alert(string);
    },
    edit2: "call default edit()"
};

object.edit2("Hello World!!");
```

How can I do that?
Sorry my english is.. bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do it like this

```
var object = {
    edit : function(string){
        alert(string);
    },
    edit2 :function(string){
        this.edit(string);
    }
};

object.edit2("Hello World!!");
```

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it.

Comment: Like ninjas *-*
Thanksss XD

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var object = {edit : function(string){alert(string)},
           edit2 : function(string){this.edit(string)}
}

object.edit2("Hello World!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Javascript allow:

```
var object = {edit : function(string){alert(string)} };
object.edit2 = object.edit;

object.edit2("Hello World!!")
```

or scrblnrd3's solution.

This website is international, so i guess you're not the only one who don't speak very well english... (Why are you looking at me ?)